# Read large lists with Office365-REST-Python-Client

Tags: rest, sharepoint-rest-api, api, office365apis, python

I am currently trying to read only the last week's entries of a few lists, and I accomplish this by using `filter("Modified gt datetime{date_in_isoformat}')` or `order_by("Modified desc").top(50)`  along with `get()`; but now one of my lists has crossed the 5000 entries threshold and I get a 500 Error because of it, if I use `paged(5000)` or `get_all(5000)` it doesn't seem to work with filter() or order_by() and top().

Is this a limitation? Do I need to chain these in a specific order?

Thank you for any insight

Answer (score 0):

When working with large lists that exceed the 5000-item threshold in SharePoint, you may encounter limitations in retrieving items using the `filter`, `orderby`, and `top` methods. This is because these methods operate on the client side and rely on retrieving all items before applying the filtering, ordering, and limiting.

To overcome this limitation, I would consider following approaches to try:

- **Paging and Sorting**: If you need to retrieve items using the REST API only, you can implement paging and sorting techniques. You can use the `startRow` parameter to specify the starting row index, and `orderby` to sort the items before applying the filter. By fetching items in smaller batches and combining the results, you can overcome the 5000 item limitation.
- **Indexed Columns**: You can create an index on the column(s) you frequently use for filtering, such as the `Modified` column in your case. Indexing allows SharePoint to efficiently retrieve items based on indexed columns, even when the list exceeds the 5000 item threshold.